# Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?

Tags: html

I see this character in Firebug `&#65279;`.

I don't know why this is happening, there's no such character in my code. For Firefox it's OK, but in IE everything breaks. I can't even search for this character in Google.

I saved my file with utf-8 encoding without bom.

[image]

Comment: no it's NOT possible duplicate read this line of that post :"Encode in UTF-8 without BOM",
and this seems to fix the problem. then read mine !!

Comment: Two different symptoms of the same problem deserve to be enshrined in two different questions, IMO.  Thanks mehdi for the screenshot of the Firebug symptom.  Thanks @Vega for the link to the ajax symptom.

Comment: If anyone is facing this problem in ASP.NET MVC with razor as view engine, then open your file in Notepad++ and check @using on top of the page. It will help you to figure out the issue.

Comment: I am also getting this problem in my MVC6 web application.

I have added below line in my layout page on very top & problem is resolved.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: Key answer ... keep your development files on ANSI/ASCII encoding

Comment: If you are in ASP.Net MVC - check whether you accidentally added a line on the very first line of your view file.

Answer (score 122):

The character in question `&#65279` is the Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). It may be that you copied it into your code via a copy/paste without realizing it. The fact that it's not visible makes it hard to tell if you're using an editor that displays actual unicode characters.

One option is to open the file in a very basic text editor that doesn't understand unicode, or one that understands it but has the ability to display any non-ascii characters using their actual codes.

Once you locate it, you can delete the small block of text around it and retype that text manually.

Comment: Go-go `notepad.exe`! Not much else it's good for. :D

Comment: I use emacs for such things, personally... but speaking to an audience with whom you're unsure of their familiarity with such tools, I figured it was best not to mention it :)

Comment: i open it with notepad no unusual character was there and i save it now i have three character at the top . hooray ! :)

Comment: This worked for me... i found the end </div> was in a different sized font which was causing the issue. Thanks for this

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not the OP !

Comment: @Mat-visual Oops, my mistake lol - I will retag my comment to the OP. I saw your comment *"This worked for me... i found the end </div> was in a different sized font which was causing the issue. Thanks for this"* and thought it was you.

Comment: Salam.
Also convert **Included file** to "UTF-8 without BOM" with notepad ++

Comment: Key answer .. convert development files to 
"ANSI" with notepad ++

Comment: I had to put in ini_set('memory_limit', '2G'); to make the script run. Also I made it into a command line script since my web user is unable to edit files. See https://gist.github.com/rlorenzo/13b4e58fc7cc47ca457a54ca8ab90c29

Answer (score 94):

Just use notepad ++ with encoding UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: This works. The Facebook Object Debugger --> Scraped URL showed me that i had &#65279; breaking my header.

Comment: @shonhloi This worked much better and easier than RHSeeger's answer

Comment: Thank You. I setted in Menu: Encoding >> Encode in UTF-8. And it worked to me. Thanks.

Comment: Just want to chime in - this works with Sublime Text, just open the offending file and choose "Save with Encoding" from the File menu and choose UTF-8.

Answer (score 45):

yeah, its so simple to fix that, just open that file by notepad++ and step follow --> Encoding\ encoding UTF-8 without BOM.
then save that.
It work for me as well!

Answer (score 36):

Try:

```
<?php 
// Tell me the root folder path.
// You can also try this one
// $HOME = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
// Or this
// dirname(__FILE__)
$HOME = dirname(__FILE__);

// Is this a Windows host ? If it is, change this line to $WIN = 1;
$WIN = 0;

// That's all I need
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>UTF8 BOM FINDER and REMOVER</title>
<style>
body { font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #FFF; color: #000; }
.FOUND { color: #F30; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$BOMBED = array();
RecursiveFolder($HOME);
echo '<h2>These files had UTF8 BOM, but i cleaned them:</h2><p class="FOUND">';
foreach ($BOMBED as $utf) { echo $utf ."<br />\n"; }
echo '</p>';

// Recursive finder
function RecursiveFolder($sHOME) {
  global $BOMBED, $WIN;

  $win32 = ($WIN == 1) ? "\\" : "/";

  $folder = dir($sHOME);

  $foundfolders = array();
  while ($file = $folder->read()) {
    if($file != "." and $file != "..") {
      if(filetype($sHOME . $win32 . $file) == "dir"){
        $foundfolders[count($foundfolders)] = $sHOME . $win32 . $file;
      } else {
        $content = file_get_contents($sHOME . $win32 . $file);
        $BOM = SearchBOM($content);
        if ($BOM) {
          $BOMBED[count($BOMBED)] = $sHOME . $win32 . $file;

          // Remove first three chars from the file
          $content = substr($content,3);
          // Write to file 
          file_put_contents($sHOME . $win32 . $file, $content);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $folder->close();

  if(count($foundfolders) > 0) {
    foreach ($foundfolders as $folder) {
      RecursiveFolder($folder, $win32);
    }
  }
}

// Searching for BOM in files
function SearchBOM($string) { 
    if(substr($string,0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) return true;
    return false; 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

copy this code to php file upload to root and run it.

for more about this: http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=98700.0

Comment: Great, this code helped me detect files with BOM. Thanks.

Comment: This is one hell of a code. Thanks

Comment: Saved our website, you are the hero!

Comment: Hero of the year, you saved me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Jumping Jelly Beans Batman!

Comment: thanks,like a charm

Comment: Can anyone please explain this code.

Comment: That code is awesome!, I was facing the same issue in wordpress, and then i creadted bom.php and put it in the root, where the wo-config is, and boom... the site is fixed now.

Comment: Be very careful running this code; it is altering the source code of your files. It will clobber all references to `ZWNBSP`; which may or may not be what you intended as some older applications will use `ZWNBSP` for formatting.

Comment: Perfectoooo!!! You're our champ @elhmahmy

Answer (score 14):

"I don't know why this is happening"

Well I have just run into a possible cause:-) Your HTML page is being assembled
from separate files. Perhaps you have files which only contain the body or banner portion of your final page. Those files contain a BOM (0xFEFF) marker. Then as part of the merge process you are running HTML tidy or xmllint over the final merged HTML file.

That will cause it!

Comment: This also applies when using **Server Side Includes**: If the included files are stored with BOM (e.g. UTF-8 with Byte Order Mark), there will be appearances of `&#65279;` in the file assembled by the webserver. Simple solution: Save the files as UTF-8 **without** Byte Order Mark.

Comment: Thank you so much, man. You have no idea how you saved my life. I had exactly the same problem.
But it's NOT ALWAYS THAT EASY BECAUSE :

.


YEAH IT'S EASY WITH NOTEPAD++ BUT JUST LIKE YOU SAY WHEN THE WEBPAGE IS MADE WITH DIFFERENT INCLUDES, IT'S A PAIN TO FIND THE CULPRIT!

.

I FINALLY FOUND IT!

.

HALLELUJAH!!!

.

.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Notepad++, "Menu" >> "Encoding" >> "Convert to UTF-8" your "include" files.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a lot of files to review, you can use this tool:
https://www.mannaz.at/codebase/utf-byte-order-mark-bom-remover/

Credits to Maurice

It help me to clean a system, with MVC in CakePhp, as i work in Linux, Windows, with different tools.. in some files my design was break.. so after checkin in Chrome with debug tool find the &#65279 error

Answer (score 5):

Before clear space (trim)

Then replace with RegEx `.replace("/\xEF\xBB\xBF/", "")`

I'm working on Javascript, I did with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

An old stupid trick that works in this case... paste code from your editor to ms notepad, then viceversa, and evil character will disappears !
I take inspiration from wyisyg/msword copypaste problem.
Notepad++ utf-8 w/out BOM works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents:
I had the same problem and I tried using Notepad++ to convert to UTF-8 no BOM, and also the old "copy to MS notepad then back again" trick, all to no avail. My problem was solved by making sure all files (and 'included' files) were **the same file system**; I had some files that were Windows format and some that had been copied off a remote Linux server, so were in UNIX format.