# whitespace and Head tags displays inside body?

Tags: php, cakephp

i was working on french site fully in cakephp,but it was causing file type encoding to embedd the characters to html .So i changed file type to `encode in utf-8` in notepad++.but its causing problem and giving whitespace and head tags coming in body of html like this-

```
&#65279;
<meta content="IE=EmulateIE9" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="IE=EmulateIE8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<title> : test</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/mapubvideoRel/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/mapubvideoRel/favicon.ico">
<link href="/mapubvideoRel/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/mapubvideoRel/css/helper.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/mapubvideoRel/css/general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/mapubvideoRel/css/colorbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/mapubvideoRel/css/App_Popup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/mapubvideoRel/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/mapubvideoRel/js/popup.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/mapubvideoRel/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript">

&#65279;
```

please help.
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9691771/474535 It seems that you can use notepad.exe to get rid of it

Comment: That's the Unicode marker for zero-width non-breaking space .. it's like a space, but worse, you can't see it

Answer (score 1):

you have file with BOM char . use BOM Detector program

java : http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=257 [recommended][find and remove]

1- check URL for exist BOM 
2- remove BOM from your file 
php : http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/04/detecting-utf-bom-byte-order-mark/

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this problem in my MVC6 web application.

I have added below line in my layout page on very top & problem is resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```