# invalid character in json response

Tags: json, cakephp-2.4

in my cakephp controller i send the json response with

```
$response = array('success' => 1);
return json_encode($response);
```

i am alway getting a wrong json in my view: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
i have tested with JSLint, the error is "unsafe Character" char 0 line 1
firebug console output returns **65279** for the following statement.

```
console.log(response.charCodeAt(0));
```

what can i do? is this an UTF-8 issue?

Answer (score 1):

You may have the character `&#65279;` in your json string which is the Unicode Character `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (U+FEFF)`. It may be that you copied it into your code via a copy/paste without realizing it. It is not visible so it is hard to debug. Try copy the $response text into a text editor and erase the space.

Here is a post that may be related.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691839/2777098