# Extra spaces appear when converting my bootstrap html files to php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a page using `Bootstrap` and everything looks ok while it is in `HTML` form but when I convert them to php, an extra vertical space appears under one of the divs.

I have 3 files here.

```
header.php
index.php
footer.php
```

The vertical space appears after the last `DIV` in the `index.php` before footer starts. It is very odd because this is not happening in HTML form, so this has to do something with `PHP` right?

```
<?php
    $url_path        = "../";
    include ($url_path . "header.php");
?>   
<div class="wrap">   
</div>
<?php
    include ($url_path . "footer.php");
?>
```

You can see where the white-space appears in these images.

After the `div class="wrap"` tag

***FireBug:***

[image]

***Chrome:***

[image]

The odd thing is that when I remove

```
<?php
    include ($url_path . "footer.php");
?>
```

and copy and paste the whole content of the `footer.php` there everything looks fine again.

Comment: does the space get added to the rendered page or just the source?

Comment: It gets added to the rendered page and the inspector displays it too, but when I click on view page source, the space is not there!

Comment: Do you have any styles on the div or something?

Comment: Are there some special hidden characters that your editor isn't picking up - try copying and pasting into notepad and then back into your footer.php and see if that works - in your firebug there seems to be an `&#65279;` - [this post may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)

Comment: @Flopet17 No, just `overflow = hidden`, and it is not because of that, when I replace the footer include part with the actual contents of the footer.php everything looks fine, I don't know what happens when I use include.

Comment: @Pete I did that too, This is the oddest thing ever happened to me while designing web pages!