# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100" while executing MapReduce

Tags: java, exception, hadoop, mapper

I'm writing a MapReduce job for finding common friends on facebook.

This is the input for my mapper :

```
100, 200 300 400 500 600
200, 100 300 400
300, 100 200 400 500
400, 100 200 300
500, 100 300
600, 100
```

And this is part of my mapper code:

```
map{
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] LineSplits = line.split(",");


        String[] friends = LineSplits[1].trim().split(" ");
        for(int i =0; i<friends.length;i++) {
            int friend2 = Integer.parseInt(friends[i]);
            System.out.println(friend2);
        }

        int friend1 = Integer.parseInt(LineSplits[0]);
        System.out.println(friend1);
}
```

When I execute this,I am getting correct values in `friend2`. (`Intege.parseInt` is working fine here).  The variable friend1 is supposed to get the value as '100'. But `Integer.ParseInt` is not working and I am getting an error like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100"
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.hadoop.CFMapper.map(CFMapper.java:29)
    at com.hadoop.CFMapper.map(CFMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So I got stuck here. Why am I getting a NumberFormatException for this? and how can I rectify this?

Comment: That is weird.  If there were any funny hidden characters like `\n` or `\r`, I would expect the error message to reflect that.  Can you do a print of `LineSplits[0].length()` before you parse it?  What does it give you?

Comment: Try printing of the code that is causing an error. Logic says that when trying to parse "100" it should work - However there might be some hidden characters such as "100\n\r". You could always just String.replace them out of the string.

Comment: `LineSplits[0].length()` returned 4

Comment: @Mounika_22 just print the string.

Comment: Ah!  Now can you print out `(int)LineSplits[0].charAt(n)`, where `n` is 0, 1, 2 and 3.  This way we can see what characters are hidden.  You don't only have digits there.  And tell us what you get for the 4 characters.

Comment: @nafas I want that to be an int so that I could use it later in the map code.

Comment: @Mounika_22 yes , I understand, but you need to find out why its giving you an error first. just print the string as everyone else suggested, if you print the string out then u know if its an integer or not

Comment: @nafas: printing the string won't be enough.  the error message he gets already prints `"100"` as the string that it can't parse.  But clearly, that string looks good.  So we need to examine it character by character.

Comment: @sstan Here is the output for that 65279
49
48
48

Comment: @sstan how do you know if the string looks good? there could be many reason that the input file is not the same as the above.

Comment: @nafas the input file is exactly the same as above

Comment: @Mounika_22 here is your problem mate, "65279" it looks like some sort of encoding, you should have recieved 49 48 48 as the output

Comment: @nafas What should I do to get rid of "65279"

Comment: @Mounika_22 r u using windows or linux?

Comment: @nafas I'm using linux

Comment: what if you simply `trim()` all Strings before parsing? `int friend2 = Integer.parseInt(friends[i].trim());` for example

Comment: @Mounika_22 before I give any other suggestion, can you try `int friend1 = Integer.parseInt(LineSplits[0].tirm());` first

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels lol :D

Comment: @nafas I tried that too, but the error stays the same.

Comment: @Mounika_22 try `int friend1 = new Scanner(LineSplits[0]).nextInt();`   <-- generally not recommended. but if it works we know how to fix the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your file has an invalid Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF).  you need to get rid of that.

The character is not visible. So it's understandable that you didn't realize that it was there.  You probably copy pasted in there by mistake.  you'll have to see where you copied your data from.

I should mention that trimming your string in code won't work to get rid of that character.  You really need to go in your input file and fix it from there.

You will find suggestions on how to get rid of the character in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html).

Otherwise, if your file is not too big, why not start a fresh new file, and type in your values manually to be safe. :)

Comment: there u see, the file is not always as it looks :)

Comment: I edited the input file. All I did was I backspaced the first line. So that invisible character was removed. Now everything works file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As you mentioned in comment the length you are getting is `4`

Maybe you can Trythis .

**`LineSplits[0].replace(u'\ufeff', '')`** and then try to parse and see what happens

---

If you look at the [Integer.parseInt() jsl](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
it says

> ```
> Throws:
>
> NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.
> ```

So what if when the `string: "100"` reaches the ENDOFLINE . It can have **character like \r\n or \n i.e `line termination` or `null`**  if the end of the stream has been reached, Which is **clearly not "parsable integer"**. So you need to check for these before parsing.

Comment: You missed part of the code regarding the first split. he splits it on the coma first, then on the spaces for the second half. E.g. "100" and " 200 300 400 500 600". Then splits the second string on spaces.