# String starts with an empty String ("")

Tags: java, string, text

My program is reading a text file and doing actions based on the text. But the first line of the text is problematic. Apparently it starts with "". This is messing my `startsWith()` checks.

To understand the problem I've used this code :

```
   System.out.println(thisLine 
        + " -- First char : (" + thisLine.charAt(0) 
        + ") - starts with ! : " 
        + thisLine.startsWith("!"));
```

`String thisLine` is the first line in the text file.

it writes this to the console : 
`! use ! to add comments. Lines starting with ! are not read. -- First char : () - starts with ! : false`

Why is this happening and how do I fix this? I want it to realize that the line starts with "!" not ""

Comment: `charAt(0)` *cannot* return an "empty string", or any *string*. What do you get from `System.out.println( (int)thisLine.charAt(0) )`?

Comment: Why don't you just check in debug the first character?

Comment: @HannoBinder I get `65279`

Comment: The first char of your line is probably an unreadable control character. Try replacing your control characters is the string firstLine with '?'. 

`my_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");`

Comment: 65279 is a zero-width space character so it would look exactly like an empty string. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html

Comment: @Buurman you are right. There is a `?` at the start now.

Comment: @Buurman notepad.exe shows nothing there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collecting mine and others' comments into one answer for posterity, your string probably contains unprintable control characters. Try

`System.out.println( (int)thisLine.charAt(0) )`

to print out their numerical code or

`my_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "?");`

to replace the control characters with '?'.

`System.out.println( (int)thisLine.charAt(0) )` printed `65279` for you which would be the Unicode code point for a zero-width space, not unprintable but effectively invisible on output. (See [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)).

Either remove the extra whitespace character from the file, remove all control characters from the string (`my_string.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");`) or use @arvind's answer and trim the string (`thisLine = thisLine.trim();`) before reading so it contains no whitespace at the very beginning or the very end of the string.

EDIT: Notepad won't show most 'special' characters. If you want to edit the file try a hex editor or a more advanced version of notepad such as Notepad++.

Comment: I'm looking for a programatic way to remove them. Trimming didn't work.

Comment: It worked thanks. But where did that character came from? I've written the text programatically.

Comment: You might have inadvertently copy-pasted the character in when you copied the string value in, ie. even if you create a string like `String s = "abcdef";`, if you copy the `abcdef` part from somewhere else you might copy in a special character which then wouldn't show in your IDE but would actually be there.

Comment: `65279` is `0xFEFF` which happens to be the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) for a file in UTF-16 encoding. So, if someone chose to write a file with a BOM in UTF-16, the first unicode character would look like the that "invisible whitespace", which at least indicates that you are using the correct endiannes when reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try truncating white spaces before:

```
thisLine = thisLine.trim();
System.out.println(thisLine 
        + " -- First char : (" + thisLine.charAt(0) 
        + ") - starts with ! : " 
        + thisLine.startsWith("!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed to what @Arvind has said. It should address the problem if the string has leading whitespaces.

But, always remember that startsWith(String arg) returns true if the arg passed is "" (empty string)

[image: source: Javadocs]

Answer (score 0):

Ignore first line if it is empty..

If you are reading lines in a loop do like below:

```
thisLine = thisLine.trim();
if (thisLine.isEmpty()) {
    continue;
}
// Remaining logic here including sysout
```

Comment: it is not empty it is `! use ! to add comments. Lines starting with ! are not read.`

Comment: Ok.. then just trimming should work. Updating my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use  the following code to see for sure what the first character of the line is and how long the line is:

```
System.out.println(thisLine 
    + " -- First char : (" + ((int)thisLine.charAt(0))
    + ") - Line length: " +  thisLine.length());
```

Comment: it is `65279` Notepad does not show anything there.

Comment: In this case it might be the best solution to always trim() the line you read before processing it (like @Arvind already mentioned)