# java.lang.NumberFormatException while reading file input

Tags: java, file, exception

```
File folderPathFile = new File("C:\\Users\\ali\\Desktop\\folderPath.txt");


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folderPathFile));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        foldersPath.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();


    String lineDup = line.toString();
        String[] LineSplits = lineDup.split(",");


        String[] array = LineSplits[1].trim().split(" ");
        for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++) {
            int fr = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
            System.out.println(fr);//its printing
        }

        int fr1 = Integer.parseInt(LineSplits[0]);
        System.out.println(fr1);
}
```

My Problem is when i run this code i've `java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "900"`

INPUT i'm Giving i.e myfile data is 900, 200 300 400 500 600

Why for 900 only i'm getting such error ?

Comment: I don't know how your code is running with arrayi]

Comment: `int fr = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);`//correct

Comment: LineSplits[0] length is 4 why ?

Comment: No `LineSplits[0].length()` is `3` only.

Comment: @Satya No it may be 4 .. see my updated ANSWER

Comment: @Ankur Anand, By testing only now I'm telling this. `LineSplits[0].length()` is `3` only.

Comment: @Satya It's 4 and Ankur's answer worked .. i wrote the line again and everything Worked :)

Comment: But I got `3` only. Sice your taking it from `file`. So that you are getting `4`.

Comment: @Satya You don't have his data file .. Those characters get Copied Sometime .. If you write fresh on your own notepad it won't be there . It's depends upon Situations from where this data was taken

Comment: That's what I'm telling.

Comment: @Satya you are generalizing it for file , Which is not always true in most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the lineSplit[0] length if it's 4 then there is an invisible character i.e [ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) . It's hard to detect as it's invisible and trimming won't delete that character. If so you need to get rid of that character

EDIT:
As you are Saying it's length is 4. try this `LineSplits[0].replace(u'\ufeff', '')` or You can write that number yourself instead of copying it from somewhere

You can check the long discussion about this character here on this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)  though it's regarding HTML but makes sense how this character comes and all

Comment: Yes it's showing 4 how to get rid of that Character ?

Comment: Worked Like ANYTHING .. I never realized this can also Happen .. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are newbie to MapReduce programming and just learning from sample input file that you have copy pasted from the web then just create input file manually as during copy paste some UTF characters also get pasted.

I solved the issue by manually creating sample file.