# why does django include tag generate text in chrome

Tags: html, django, google-chrome

I use django include tag. Then I browse it in chrome, and I found layout of the web page is wrong. I use programmer tool and find some text generated by chrome at the position of django include tag.

The text is 
`"                &#65279"`

why does django include tag generate text in chrome. How I can fix it?

Comment: Please add your include tag code from template to your question.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html

Answer (score 0):

Encode your file with UTF8 without BOM in your editor.

Answer (score 0):

I use notepad++ and save all the templates in UTF 8 and it fixed the problem for me.

In notepad++ go to Encoding -> UTF8 then save the file.