# Can't get rid of the invisible sign

Tags: html, dom, utf-8, special-characters

I found invisible sign in my DOM. It is strange that I dont have it on my local website. When I send it on the server it appears there.

I tried copying this file to notepad++ and converting to UTF-8 without BOM and I was copying and pasting it to notepad.exe but also without any result. The server page keeps showing me this sign.

I also clicked in notepad++ to show me all invisible signs and it shows only CR LF.

Browser inspect of the file on my local machine:

[image]

Browser inspect of the file on the server:

[image]

Why it keeps showing there? and why the head content is moved to body?

I'm sure that aliens did it! Please help me.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html

Answer (score 0):

The invisible character was hiding in `.env` file or one of the config files. I just converted them all to `utf8 without bom` in my notepad++ and its fine now!

ps. Yes, I still think that aliens did it!