# Whitespace between divs for no reason?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace

I have a div and it has random whitespaces above and below it.

I've uploaded it to my host where you can clearly see this:
I've tried to figure it out for hours.. no margins or paddings on footer/header. When I inspect the white space it directs me to "body". Didn't find any strange things under body.

It's probably a simple issue but.. how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @IvRRimUm I've posted a link above to the website. It's a piece of my project and I don't know where the issue is in my 469 lines of .css file (probably too long to post here). You can inspect element and access stylesheet here: http://keller.smehitus.ee/css/landing-page.css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see when inspecting the HTML, there's a *Zero width no-breaking space* (`&#65279;`) above and underneath. You'll have to find them in your HTML markup and remove them.
https://puu.sh/ul26W/6f1c2b695f.png

Comment: It can help to remove it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html

Comment: @Mathias-w how do you see the whitespaces? not visible in my firefox. Thanks btw

Comment: @ScottJames you're right on this and I honestly don't know why Firefox doesn't render them at all immediately. You can however spot them if you edit the body through the FF devtools - right-click on body and select **Edit as HTML**. You can then see red dots which represents these entities in the HTML. For the record, I'm using Google Chrome.