# PHP Switch Case with Include Breaks Following Code

Tags: php, include, switch-statement, parse-error

My code was working before I included it in an external file.

In my main file:

```
switch($data){
case 'test': include_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.php');
break;
}
```

In test.php:

```
<?php 
echo 'bark bark';
?>
```

What I get when I try to load the main file :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'break' (T_BREAK) in /(......directory info removed)/mainfile.php on line 3
```

I have tried many different ways to reference the directory path, including the full path (public_html, etc), and nothing seems to load it. I am using Wordpress; not sure if that makes a difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is a character `&#65279` - `'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'` after your `;` in `include_once`. You should have copy pasted from somewhere. Just remove the last character or try typing manually. This fixes!

[image]

Read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691839/5447994)

Comment: Very weird, never ran into this before, but re-typing it fixed it --- thank you!!!

Comment: Yes sometimes this happens with copy pasting :D