# getting strange character while loading view in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, view

Getting strange character while loading a view in codeigniter view.

**Main View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?PHP $this->load->view("common/header"); ?>
</head>
<body class="page-header-fixed">
</body>
</html>
```

**Header View**

```
<title><?PHP echo $this->config->item('project_name'); ?>| Dashboard</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="<?PHP echo $this->config->item('project_name'); ?> | Dashboard" />
<meta name="keywords" content="admin,dashboard" />
```

when i inspect in chrome it's shows ﻿ above of loaded view and put space in view

**please see attached image**

[image]

Comment: somewhere you are echoing something. CI doesn't do this by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character in question &#65279 is the Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). It may be that you copied it into your code via a copy/paste without realizing it. The fact that it's not visible makes it hard to tell if you're using an editor that displays actual unicode characters.

[Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)