# vswprintf keeps prefixing a Byte Order Mark character

Tags: c, printf

I am still a rookie with C, and even newer to wide chars in C.

The below code should show

`4 points to Smurfs`

but it shows

`4 points to  Smurfs`

In gdb I *see* this:

```
(gdb) p buffer
$1 = L" 4 points to  Smurfs",
```

But when I copy paste from the console, the spaces are magically gone:

```
(gdb) p buffer
$1 = L"4 points to Smurfs",
```

Also, `buffer[0]` contains this according to `gdb`:
`65279 L' '`

Apparently the character in question &#65279 is the Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). I retyped the code making sure I did not enter this. I don't know where this comes from. I also opened the code in notepad per https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691839/7602 and there is no extra chars there.

I wouldn't care if ncurses would stop showing this as a space.

Code (heavily cut down):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define NCURSES_WIDECHAR 1
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>

#include "types.h"
#include "defines.h"
#include "externs.h"

WINDOW * term;

/*row column color n arguments */
void rccn(int row, int col, const wchar_t *fmt, ...)
{
    wchar_t buffer[80];
    int size;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    size = vswprintf(buffer, 80, fmt, args);
    va_end( args );

    if(size >= 80){
        mvaddwstr(row, col, L"Possible hacker detected!");
    }else{
        mvaddwstr(row, col, buffer);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    term = initscr();

    rccn(1,1,L"%i points to %ls",4,L"Smurfs");
    ch = getch();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem goes 'away' with
`rccn(1,1,L"%i points to %ls",4,L"Smurfs"+1);`

As if the wide encoding of the constant adds that char in front..

Comment: Perhaps change to `L"<%i> points to <%ls>"` to narrow the issue.

Comment: Super interesting, I get `<4> points to < Smurfs>`

Comment: If you run the code and redirect output to a file `a.out > t.bin`, what does a dump of the file show?

Comment: Part of the mix is curses with wide support, t.bin is empty

Comment: It sounds like Windows doing something weird with byte order marks (U+FEFF is used as a byte order mark character).

Comment: I actually run the code on Raspbian, just use Atom on Windows to do the coding with the ftp plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Found it..

I had followed a tutorial where it was advised to add this compiler flag:
`-fwide-exec-charset=utf-32`

My code was not running on Cygwin at all, and I read that Windows is utf-16 centered, so I removed that compiler flag and it started working on Cygwin.

Then out of curiosity I removed the compiler flag on Raspbian, and it is now working as expected there as well, no more byte order marks.