# Extra Space in laravel template integration

Tags: php, templates, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I have created some layouts and added in home.blade.php, when i view it in browser some space is added whenever i include the layouts! here is my home.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>@yield('title') - {!! trans('main.site_title') !!}</title>    <!-- Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="{!! URL::to('/') !!}/public/frontend/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    {{ Html::style('public/frontend/js/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css') }}
    {{ Html::style('public/frontend/js/flexslider/flexslider.css') }}
    {{ Html::style('public/frontend/js/radial-progress/style.css') }}
    {{ Html::style('public/frontend/css/animate.css') }}
  
</head>
<body>
@include('frontend.layouts.header')
@include('frontend.layouts.slider')
@include('frontend.layouts.header_strips')
    @include('frontend.layouts.news_events')
    @include('frontend.layouts.share_pics_articles')
    @include('frontend.layouts.are_you_ready')
    @include('frontend.layouts.education_great')
    @include('frontend.layouts.about_statistics')
    @include('frontend.layouts.quotes')
    @include('frontend.layouts.sub_footer')
    @include('frontend.layouts.footer')

    {!! Html::script('public/frontend/js/breakpoints.js') !!}
    {!! Html::script('public/frontend/js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js') !!}
    {!! Html::script('public/frontend/js/scrollspy.js') !!}
</body>

</html>
```

How to fix that issue ? can some one help me please
Below i have attached the browser screenshot please take a look at it !
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)

Comment: May i know why this is occuring ?

Comment: If I follow the answers posted in the linked thread, you've probably pasted some code that contained a weird utf-8 space character. Or you deliberately typed it, but that's probably not the case.

Comment: i did still the same issue occurs !