# How to remove &#65279; from wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I removed this special character using string locator but still live on my site.
http://prntscr.com/ke7pby 
**It's just before my footer are.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the code as *text* inside the question, not as an image. Also, please see these guidelines for creating helpful questions: 
[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html#9691839) answer :

> Just use notepad ++ with encoding UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I did both file front-page.php and footer.php . sadly it didn't work for me.