# Blank space in web page above footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create my personal website.
However there is a blank space above the footer i cannot eliminate.
You can find online my website here:

http://www.gx-personal.site/index.php

There is an unexplained blank space above the footer which is more visible at interests and contact pages because the color of background is different.
I have reviewed my code many times looking for padding and margins that might create that to no avail.

The problem seems to be the main tag.
The blank space behaves differently depending on the main's tag display property.
More specifically:
Block will crate space above and below the main section.
Grid (existing) creates blank space below.
Inline-block eliminates the blank space above and below but creates blank space on the right.

To help i will provide the following info:
Each page has 2 css files.
One that manages the header/ main navigation menu and footer and is common for all pages called mysite.css
And a specific css for each page.

The easier way to see the problem is with the interests page as there is no content there.
i have included some comments into the css files to indicate what the problem might be.

How can i eliminate this blank space and why is it created in the first place?
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following content after a script tag just above the footer:

```
    &#65279;
```

It is rendering with 0 width but 19px of height in Chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html/9970264#9970264

Answer (score 0):

One of your bottom classes, **"phome"**, has a margin-bottom of 274.075px directly inline.

And it is also an empty one, so I would look there first.

Comment: I know. This is intentional in order ot keep the last phome class alittle longer on the screen However this is not affecting the other pages as this css is only loaded on the specific page.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But JasonB found it :-)

Comment: Ye apparently the error was from php and this BOM thing. Funny thing is i used notepad++ to create texts but...