# rendered handlebars partials with node.js printing unnecessary spaces

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm new at node.js and i'm using handlebars(hbs), i have created a views and some partials, and everything goes well, but the problem is the rendered partials have unnecessary spaces which makes the page looks bad, here is my code :
handlebars view

```
{{>header}}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{{>footer}}
```

handlebars partial (footer)

```
<footer>
   Created By Hassan Ali
</footer>
```

and here is my app.js

```js
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const hbs = require("hbs")
const app = express()

// Folders Pathes
var publicFolder = path.join(__dirname, "../public")
var viewsFolder = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/pages")
var partialsFolder = path.join(__dirname, "../templates/components")

// Setting The View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
// Setting The Views Directory
app.set('views', viewsFolder)
// Setting The Views Components
hbs.registerPartials(partialsFolder)
// Setting The Static Folder
app.use(express.static(publicFolder))

app.get("/notes", (req, res) => {
   res.render("notes", {
      title: "Notes App"
   })
})
```

and when it's rendered i get some unnecessary spaces in the html before every partial with this &-#65279; entity (without - that after &)

```html
&#65279;
<header>
Header Tag
</header>

<h1>Title of The Page</h1>

&#65279;
<footer>
   Created By Hassan Ali
</footer>
```

any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: The problem is solved Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is &#65279; appearing in my HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html)