# How to find and remove unexpected line of code in HTML

Tags: html, css, utf-8, frontend

I was playing with my website's front-end recently and I don't know how but the following line of code got into the `<body>` of some of my html files and I can't find where this line is in my files so that I can remove it:

```
              &#65279;
```

And here's an image of what I see when I inspect my pages with the `DevTools`:

[image: a busy cat]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post all the code you have. I guarantee it's in there somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9691771/1263904

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character in question &#65279 is the Unicode Character Unicode Character ['ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)

Just open that file by notepad++ then step follow --> Encoding\ encoding UTF-8 without `BOM` then save your file.

Comment: Thanks for that, I use Atom as code editor so will it work with this one too?

Comment: Yes you can do it with ATOM too it's listed below