# Getting error while executing powershell script from powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am getting the below error while executing the below code
Code :

```
$localScriptPath= "C:\AshishG\powershell\script12.ps1"
$ëncodedResonse = "77u/V3JpdGUtSG9zdCAnc2NyaXB0IGlzIGV4ZWN1dGVkIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseScNCg0KcmV0dXJuICdUaGlzIGlzIHNjcmlwdCBvdXRwdXQn"
Write-Output "ëncodedResonse used is $ëncodedResonse"

[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ëncodedResonse)) | Out-File $localScriptPath -Force
$Content2 = get-content $localScriptPath
Write-Host "DECODED: " $Content2

$output =Invoke-Expression "& `"$localScriptPath`" "
Write-Host "scriptPath" used is $output
```

Code explanation:

1. Assign the path of the script into a variable.
2. assign the encoded string to a variable
3. decoding the string and copy into a file.
4. Executing the PowerShell script and getting the error.

Error:

```
Write-Host : The term 'Write-Host' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\AshishG\powershell\script12.ps1:1 char:1
+ Write-Host 'script is executed successfully'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Host:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Please see the below points.

1. I am getting the error while executing the powerscript (C:\AshishG\powershell\script12.ps1).
2. The string is in an encoded format and I can decode it and I see, the decoded string is also fine.
3. I observe, The script12.ps1 is generated in UTF-16 LE BOM format. is it creating the issue?

I have written complete code because I am not sure what is the issue?

Comment: Just run "Write-Host hello world" in the terminal, is it ok?

Comment: yes, i am able to do it.

Comment: I suspect the issue from the encodage of your file.

Comment: In PowerShell version 5.x, the default encoding for `Out-File` is **Unicode** (Utf16-LE), but you are expecting Utf8 (with or without BOM). This means the script is choking on the Byte Order Mark with which the file content starts (0xFF 0xFE). Use `Set-Content` or change the encoding of the file by using parameter `-Encoding`

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the `.ps1` file you've created, most likely coming from the encoded string.

You have a non-printing character preceding `"Write-host..."` as evidenced by executing the following after creating your `.ps1` file:

```
PS C:\>>[int[]][Char[]]((gc $localScriptPath)[0])[0]
65279
PS C:\>
```

[&#65279](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691771/why-is-65279-appearing-in-my-html) is a Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). **PowerShell** is glomming it with `Write-HOst` to create an unrecognizable command.